# Making a cremeaux lighter with whipped cream. Is there a name for this?

Tags: whipped-cream, consistency, filling

Making a cremeux lighter with whipped cream. Is there a name for this? I used this method to make a lighter filling and it was great. I know diplomat cream is similar but I was just wondering if there's a name for lightening a cremeux with whipped cream.

Edit: "cremeaux" to proper spelling of "cremeux". ;-)

Comment: What's a "cremeaux"  ? can you share a recipe ?

Comment: What is a Cremeux exactly? Well, it translates to “creamy” in French, and it is dessert that looks like a mousse but extra creamy. Also it’s incredibly versatile, it can be served by its own, maybe with some toppings or you can use it to fill a pie, doughnuts, decorate a cake, spread on a toast, anything you want.
https://www.santabarbarachocolate.com/blog/cremeux-recipe/

Comment: Welcome to the site @JaneWIlkie, can you please edit your question and add the recipe and method to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name for this is still 'cremeaux', nothing changes.

In English pastry jargon, "cremeaux" is a (somewhat rarely used) umbrella cream for any sweet filling with a creamy consistency. It is not connected to a specific recipe or technique. If the thickness is such that you can pipe it, and the texture is more similar to a custard than to, say, jam, then it can be called a cremeaux.

An alternative word for a substance of this consistency is "cream", as in "buttercream" or "shaving cream". The difference is that it is also used outside of the culinary context, and when it is used in culinary language, it can be confused with "cream" the dairy liquid made by partially removing the water from milk. I suspect that some people use the word "cremeaux" to avoid the confusion, and others just because it sounds fancier.

So, if you take a random recipe that can be called a cremeaux, maybe a custard of the right thickness, and then fold whipped cream into it, you still have something that is sweet, pipeable, and creamy in mouthfeel. Which makes again the word "cremeaux" applicable.

Depending on the final texture, the result may also fall under the term "mousse". The mousse's central characteristic is that it is very airy, while still spoonable. If you added a lot of whipped cream, and managed to keep most of the air in, it may be recognizable as a mousse.

Comment: Exactly the ( accepted ) answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Re: "an alternate word for this substance is cream..." How about "pastry cream"?

Comment: @Damila no, pastry cream is a very specific type of cream. It is made with eggs, starch and dairy. Cremeaux is a much broader term.